# Vue - Apply "v-model" on user-defined component which use ace-editor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ace-editor

---

### Code

**CodeEditor.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div class="ace-container">
    <div class="ace-editor" ref="ace"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ace from 'ace-builds'
  import 'ace-builds/webpack-resolver'
  import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-monokai'
  import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-javascript'

  export default {
    mounted() {
      this.aceEditor = ace.edit(this.$refs.ace, {
        maxLines: 60,
        minLines: 10,
        fontSize: 14,
        theme: this.themePath,
        mode: this.modePath,
        tabSize: 4
      })
    },
    data() {
      return {
        aceEditor: null,
        themePath: 'ace/theme/monokai',
        modePath: 'ace/mode/javascript'
      }
    },
    methods: {
      setCode(code) {
        this.aceEditor.setValue(code);
      },
      getCode() {
        return this.aceEditor.getValue();
      },
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .ace-editor {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
  }
</style>
```

**QuizExecution.vue:** *(partly)*

```
<template>
  <v-app height="100%">
    <div id="qz-wrapper">
      <!--
      <v-textarea id="programmingText" v-model="answerData[question.id]"
                  @change="saveAnswer(qe.id, question.id)" label="Code" outlined></v-textarea>
      -->

      <CodeEditor id="programmingText" v-model="answerData[question.id]"
                  @change="saveAnswer(qe.id, question.id)"></CodeEditor>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import CodeEditor from "./CodeEditor";

  export default {
    components: {CodeEditor},
    data() {
      return {
        // ..
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

---

### Description

With `vuetify`'s `<v-textarea>`, I can use `v-model` to bind its content to a data property, in bi-direction dynamically, so that could init on load, and save on change with a `@change` property.

Then I want to replace the input area with `ace-editor`, which support features like syntax highlight.

So, I have defined a component as in `CodeEditor.vue`, then import & use it in `QuizExecution.vue`.

But, the `v-model` and `@change` won't work on the `<CodeEditor>` tag.

---

### Questions

- How to apply `v-model` and `@click` on this `<CodeEditor>` with in `QuizExecution.vue`.
  Aka. init it with data from container component, and retrieve its content on change and trigger an event to save.
- Or, is there anyway to achieve the same result: init on creation & save on change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use props and watch the change events with @update_question_id;

```
 <CodeEditor id="programmingText" :question_id="answerData[question.id]"
              @update_question_id="answerData[question.id]=@event"
              ></CodeEditor>
....
watch:{
  answerData(){
     saveAnswer(this.qe.id, this.question.id)
  }
}
```

CodeEditor.vue:
You can get the question_id value with props. I think it would be string or number.
And also watch question_id then use $emit to send change $event to main component.

```
export default {
    props:{
      question_id: [String,Number]
    },
    watch:{
       question_id(val){
          this.$emit("update_question_id",val)
       }
    }
 .....
```

Comment: Thanks, let me investigate a bit.